# Simple button to check form validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm just trying to create a simple button to check if an input field is empty and style it accordingly. I feel like this should be really simple but I'm just missing something.

```
<input id="text"></input>
<button id="button">check</button>
<script>
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

function checker() {
   if (text.value === "") {
    text.style.cssText = "background:red;";
    return false;
   }
   else {
       text.style.cssText = "background:green;";
   }
}

button.addEventListener("click", checker(), false);
</script>
```

And here's the link to a jsfiddle that I was using to try and get it to work.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/spencerlarry/9KtSX/)

Comment: Why aren't you using jquery? It's much more easy and you can use the function .submit on a form
https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Well, I'm just starting to learn javascript and I figured I'd learn that first to at least get the basics down before I tried to learn anything else like jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing a reference to the `checker()` function, you are actually calling the function and passing the result.

What you want to do is pass a reference to the function like this...

```
button.addEventListener("click", checker, false);
```

Note the lack of `()`

Comment: Thanks for your help and for such a fast response!

Comment: Not a problem - easy to spot when you know what you're looking for. Good luck with your journey into javascript/jquery :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the function by reference:

```
button.addEventListener("click", checker, false);
```

Note: you could also pass an anonymous function:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){checker();}, false);
```